# not null default date in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a new table that following code below;

```
create table dwh.dim_produk (
sk_produk serial primary key,
kode_produk varchar(25),
nama_produk varchar(50),
kode_kategori varchar(50),
nama_kategori varchar(50),
date_from date not null default current_timestamp,
date_to date not null default '12/31/9999');
```

but i get result such as;

```
SQL Error [22008]: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "12/31/9999"
Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
Position: 253
```

thank in advance

Comment: That is a strange default date. Why not use NULL? And the default date format is `9999-12-31`

Comment: If you really think that the 9999 year is better then the present one: `make_date(year => 9999, month => 12, day => 31)`

Comment: The issue is due to your `datestyle` setting. In `psql` do `show datestyle`.  You have one that has a `DMY` ordering so the `31` in the string is out of range. Change the value to `31/12/999` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a date that is "in the future", use `infinity`

```
date_from date not null default current_date,
date_to date not null default 'infinity'
```

Or if you really want a date in the year 9999, use a proper DATE literal formatted using ANSI style:

```
date_from date not null default current_date,
date_to date not null default DATE '9999-12-31'
```

Alternatively you can represent a range using the `daterange` data type:

```
valid_during daterange not null default daterange(current_date,null)
```

A `null` for the upper range means "infinity" as well.